# C++ difference in behavior between if statement setting condition to true and or-ing a condition in loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, set, logical-or

I was working on Datalog interpreter for my CS class and I ran into a strange problem where my Rule evaluations took too many passes to complete. After looking at my code I made two modifications in the following that fixed my evaluations to execute in the correct number of passes:

```
//original form
bool addedFacts = false;
for (X x: xs) {
    addedFacts = addedFacts || set.insert(x).second;
}
//modified form
bool addedFacts = false;
for (X x: xs) {
    if (set.insert(x).second) {
        addedFacts = true;
    }
}
```

To me these two code structures appear logically equivalent. Is there a reason why one executes correctly and one execute incorrectly/inefficiently?
Here is a buildable example of the problem that was occurring:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using std::set;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

const int CAP = 100;

class Rule {
public:
    int factor;
    Rule(int factor) {
        this->factor = factor;
    }
    bool evaluateInefficient(set<int>& facts) {
        vector<int> data;
        bool addedFacts = false;
        for (int fact : facts) {
            data.push_back(fact);
        }
        for (int datum : data) {
            int newFact = datum * factor;
            if (newFact < CAP) {
                addedFacts = addedFacts || facts.insert(newFact).second;
            }
        }
        return addedFacts;
    }
    bool evaluate(set<int>& facts) {
        vector<int> data;
        bool addedFacts = false;
        for (int fact : facts) {
            data.push_back(fact);
        }
        for (int datum : data) {
            int newFact = datum * factor;
            if (newFact < CAP) {
                if (facts.insert(newFact).second) {
                    addedFacts = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return addedFacts;
    }
};

int doublyInefficient(vector<Rule>& rules) {
    set<int> facts;
    facts.insert(1);
    bool addedFacts = true;
    int passes = 0;
    while (addedFacts) {
        passes++;
        addedFacts = false;
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            addedFacts = addedFacts || rule.evaluateInefficient(facts);
        }
    }
    return passes;
}

int singlyInefficient(vector<Rule>& rules) {
    set<int> facts;
    facts.insert(1);
    bool addedFacts = true;
    int passes = 0;
    while (addedFacts) {
        passes++;
        addedFacts = false;
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            addedFacts = addedFacts || rule.evaluate(facts);
        }
    }
    return passes;
}

int efficient(vector<Rule>& rules) {
    set<int> facts;
    facts.insert(1);
    bool addedFacts = true;
    int passes = 0;
    while (addedFacts) {
        passes++;
        addedFacts = false;
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            if (rule.evaluate(facts)) {
                addedFacts = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return passes;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //build the rules
    vector<Rule> rules;
    rules.push_back(Rule(2));
    rules.push_back(Rule(3));
    rules.push_back(Rule(5));
    rules.push_back(Rule(7));
    rules.push_back(Rule(11));
    rules.push_back(Rule(13));
    //Show three different codes that should (in my mind) take the same amount of passes over the rules but don't
    cout << "Facts populated after " << doublyInefficient(rules) << " passes through the Rules." << endl;
    cout << "Facts populated after " << singlyInefficient(rules) << " passes through the Rules." << endl;
    cout << "Facts populated after " << efficient(rules) << " passes through the Rules." << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

I get the following output when running in debug and release mode (32-bit) on visual studio 2017. To my knowledge the code is not optimized.

```
Facts populated after 61 passes through the Rules.
Facts populated after 17 passes through the Rules.
Facts populated after 7 passes through the Rules.
```

Comment: In the first case, once `set.insert(x).second` is true, the loop does nothing at all. In the second case, `set.insert(x)` is called every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difference arises because of short-circuit evaluation:
Consider an expression of the form `(expr1 || expr2)`. Short-circuit means that if `expr1` evaluates to `true`, expression `expr2` will not get evaluated at all (cf. [this online c++ standard draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.log.or#1), ephasis are mine):

> *5.15 Logical OR operator*
>
> The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause [conv]). It returns true if
>   either of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, ||
>   guarantees left-to-right evaluation; **moreover, the second operand is
>   not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true**.

Hence, in your expression `addedFacts || set.insert(x).second`, from the point where `addedFacts` becomes `true` the first time, expression `set.insert(x).second` will not get executed any more. I suppose that this is the "wrong" behaviour, as your `set` will not contain the respective `x`es then.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what was going on. The program was supposed to evaluate each rule on every pass and within each rule add every new fact. The short circuit evaluation prevented my code from doing so, thus drastically increasing the number of passes required. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
addedFacts = addedFacts || set.insert(x).second;
```

and

```
if (set.insert(x).second) {
    addedFacts = true;
}
```

Are definitely not the same thing. The first block of code is equivalent to:

```
if (!addedFacts) {
    addedFacts = set.insert(x).second;
}
```

the `!addedFacts` check makes a big difference.